# Create Table using a variable in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to use a python output to create table in sqlite3. I've tried some possibilities but the script create tables with the given name. Is it possible to create a table with a variable?

```
for name in test.all():
    return name
```

or just

```
name = 'dbName'
#
conn = sqlite3.connect("my_db")
db = conn.cursor()
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE (here var)(id, column1, column2, column2)''')
conn.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: you need to look into String concatenation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with string formatting:

```
sql_cmd = '''CREATE TABLE {}(id, column1, column2, column2)'''.format(
            'table_name')
db.execute(sql_cmd)
```

Replace `'table_name'` with your desire.